# how to get email address from web page using selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I want to write a code to extract the email address from this website https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g186389-d14025284-Reviews-The_Queen_s_Head-Dorking_Surrey_England.html

this is what the email address looks like bookings@thequeensheaddorking.com?subject=?

and is inside the className "IdiaP Me sNsFa" and tag "a href"

I want to do this using selenium webdriver and javascript inside the wrapper. This is my code below.

```
            email = driver.execute_script(
                "return document.getElementsByClassName('YDAvY R2 F1 e k').getElementsByTagName('a')
)
```

i have try doing this

```
            email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="component_52"]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/a')
```

but i have got the error - ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurant_Review-g186389-d14025284-Reviews-The_Queen_s_Head-Dorking_Surrey_England.html

Comment: You know, you could just use the selector `a[href^="mailto:"]`.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName` accepts **1** class, not a selector. Use `document.querySelector` instead.

Comment: I don't see how the second code sample could cause the claimed error.  Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: Not sure what that means, but the JS you provided is invalid (you're having single quotes in single quotes)

Comment: @code what is the valid JS should look like ?

Comment: This would be valid: `email = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector(\`a[href^='mailto:']\`)") print('email', email)`

Comment: thanks @code i am now getting back this <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="c302697bd8bb2f03fffcd275c56be539", element="6c0e001f-5422-4c4e-88bc-29dc7bcff96e")> how do i get the actual email from this ?

Comment: `email = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector(\`a[href^='mailto:']\`).href.slice(7).split('?')[0]") print('email', email)`